# Check textbox before submitting

Tags: javascript, html, search

How could I check a textbox before submition?

```
<form action='search.php' method='GET'>

         <input type="text" id= "q" name="q" class='textbox' >

         <input type="submit" id='submit' value="Search" class ='button' >

     </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple with JavaScript validation:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check()
            {
                var searchtext = document.getElementById("q").value;
                if(searchtext=='')
                {
                    alert('Enter any character');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action='search.php' method='GET' onSubmit="return check();">
            <input type="text" id= "q" name="q" class='textbox' >
            <input type="submit" id='submit' value="Search" class ='button' >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the action attribute of the form tag means he needs to validate with PHP

Comment: oh ok. sorry, thought you were validating during submit. still a good idea to validate with PHP though since it is running a PHP script

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['q']))
{
//if it is not empty, do something
}
else
{
//otherwise do this
}
?>
```

May I also recommend using POST rather than GET if you're sending something from a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) as in the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        if($('#q').val() != null && $('#q').val().length > 0){
            $.get('search.php', $('#formId').serialize(), function(result){});
        }
        else{
            //Otherwise do this
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: thats quite complicated for simple validation

Comment: Do you have simpler solution?

Comment: you don't need to use jquery, that's quite complicated for what he needs to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use some stylish jQuery library for easy coding like [jQuery validation plugin](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2).

Comment: thanks, I preffer not to use jquery, as it makes performance issues