# JS confirm work with form validation, but validation word not show

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I've made an html form and I want to make it that it requires input, and submit before js confirms this so it works right:

```
<form action="someAction" method="post">
    <input type="text" required/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('sure to submit?');">test</button>
</form>
```

If it's not confirmed, it means that we did not input something into the required input tag. Then there an info box will appear to tell you.
But with confirm, the infobox disappears.

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check textbox before submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997632/check-textbox-before-submitting)

Comment: That menas I need check every required input manually before confirm? doesn't any other way?

Comment: Yes, there are **lots** of other ways. Like I said, do some research. Here's a starter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation. There are also lots of [libraries for this](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB843GB843&ei=UjYoXYyABI2igAbA1JjoBw&q=validation+javascript+library&oq=validation+javascript+lib&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0j0i22i30l2.1431.2062..2773...0.0..0.60.235.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.VnSsz8yOmY8)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want your code looks like this ...

***Updated*** *use html validation and if you want*

```js
function validate(){
 var collection = document.forms["myForm"].elements;
 for(var k in collection){
  if(collection[k].type === 'text'){ 
   if(collection[k]['value']!== '') { 
    console.log(collection[k]['value']);
   }else{ 
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 return true;
}

function onSubmit(){
  if(confirm('Confirm this action')) return true; // submit the form
  
  // else, manualy validate in js each form element value
 console.log(`The form is valide : ${validate()}`);
   
  alert('Some Info to dislay'); // display info
  return false; // prevent submit event
}
```

```html
<form action="someAction" method="post" name="myForm" onSubmit="return onSubmit();">
<!-- validate in html -->
<input name="data" required type="text" />
<input name="blabla" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
<input type="submit"  value="test"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Roughly, but I want to find a quickly way without manually check every input.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, share to every one.

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if (!confirm("Sure to submit?")) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

It will check required input first, then trigger the submit event and confirm it.

Comment: This could be shortened to `return confirm("Sure to submit?");`

Comment: I'm also not clear how this "does validation" as you requested